# Which Java Profiling tool do you use and which tool you think is the best?

Tags: java, profiler, profiling

Want to know what the stackoverflow community feels about the various free and non-free Java Profilers and profiling tools available.

Comment: You may find some help here: ["If you have a Java application that is consuming CPU when it isn’t doing anything how do you determine what it is doing?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927/if-you-have-a-java-application-that-is-consuming-cpu-when-it-isnt-doing-anythin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JProfiler works very well for us.

http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

Answer (score 4):

Yourkit is pretty good for CPU analysis.

For memory usage analsis using heap dumps use http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: +1 for YourKit which I've also used, mainly for CPU profiling

Answer (score 0):

You ask what do we use.

Tools are fine, but for finding time-tumors, frankly I've seen nothing that works better than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266373/one-could-use-a-profiler-but-why-not-just-halt-the-program/317160#317160).

Comment: that is equivalent to cpu sampling

Comment: @Seun: They do not all sample the stack. For those that sample the stack, they do not all do it on wall-clock time. For those that do sample the stack on wall-clock time, they do not all present the results in the most useful way. Rather they only summarize over functions and the call graph. Here is a case study and more detailed explanation of the method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773