# Open Source Java Profilers

Tags: java, profiler

What can you guys recommend to use with Java?

Only requirement is it should be open source, or has not too expensive academic licence .

Comment: When you say open source do you mean free? They have different meanings. Is your question about _inexpensive profilers?

Comment: free as in freedom or free as in gratis? Oh the confusion!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The VisualVM which comes with jdk6 has a basic profiler inside it.
VisualVM is provided with the jdk, so if you have the jdk6 installed, you likely have it installed as well.

https://visualvm.github.io/

Comment: The VisualVM profiler is a stand-alone version of the one in NetBeans.  It is a VERY good start.

Comment: Definitely download the most updated version on: https://visualvm.dev.java.net/ . Also: this IS the profiler NetBeans uses.

Comment: I've used `VisualVM` before with success, but it was crashing for me while trying to profile a Tomcat app. This worked for me: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/honest-profiler

Comment: honest-profiler doesn't work on JVM 11 and the author is not actively working on the project atm. https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/honest-profiler/issues/255

Answer (score 23):

you've got a list [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) (listing them below, in-case link gets broken)

> - JMemProf
> - JMP
> - DrMem
> - JTreeProfiler
> - NetBeans Profiler
> - JAMon API
> - JBoss Profiler
> - MessAdmin
> - InfraRED
> - TomcatProbe
> - Java Interactive Profiler (JIP)
> - Profiler4j
> - Stopwatch
> - JMeasurement
> - DJProf
> - TIJmp
> - Allmon
> - Appspy
> - EurekaJ
> - japex
> - OKTECH Profiler
> - Perf4j

Comment: You can add this to the list: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/honest-profiler

Answer (score 18):

Ah. [Netbeans Profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/), developer.com's "Product of the Year" winner, in 2009.

Answer (score 12):

Java has a basic built in profiler called [HProf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html).  I find it useful to compare the results it provides with results from more fully features profilers.

Comment: I've used HPROF for years - and while it may not be pretty, it's helped me solve countless memory and performance issues.

Comment: HPROF often finds different points to optimise.  I often use it after YourKit no longer gives me obvious points to optimise.

Comment: Removed since jdk 9. http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/240

Answer (score 7):

The open-source tool [jvmtop](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop) does include a basic console profiler.
Example output:

```
 JvmTop 0.7.0 alpha - 15:16:34,  amd64,  8 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-27, load avg 0.41
 http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

 Profiling PID 24015: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

  36.16% (    57.57s) hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calcChangeSet()
  30.36% (    48.33s) hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogParser.parse()
   7.14% (    11.37s) org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.parseScript()
   6.25% (     9.95s) net.sf.json.JSONObject.write()
   3.13% (     4.98s) ....kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CustomTagLibrary.loadJellyScri()
```

Answer (score 4):

[Eclipse TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/)

Here's an article about [Java Application Profiling using TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html) and here's a tutorial [Profiling J2SE 5.0 based applications using Eclipse TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/platform/documents/tutorials/jvmti/Java_Application_Profiling_using_TPTP-v2.0.html).

Comment: I've never been able to set TPTP up. Perhaps I'm too dumb to use it.

Comment: @quant_dev: I have had the same problem but somehow accidently managed to have it set up suddenly (eclipse restarted or whatever?). But when I used it it turned out to be almost useless, was incredibly slow and resource hungry to the point where I had kill eclipse. Some of the more usefull views that were mentioned in several references I found online also don't seem to exist anymore in the current realease that works with eclipse 3.5. So at the moment it's basically just a huge BLOB of uselessness.

Comment: Eclipse TPTP looks like a mature product but is extremely slow. I cannot understand why...

Comment: Unfortunately TPTP has now had its final release (v4.7.2). It has been archived and is no longer part of the Eclipse simultaneous release.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a no-frills, easy to use open source profiler, you may want to take a look at Jip ([Java Interactive Profiler](http://jiprof.sourceforge.net/)). It's published under a BSD license. I found it to be quite useful for small programs. At least, the results it gives are way more easy to understand than hprofs output.

Answer (score 3):

[Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control), it's free to use for development and it integrates with Eclipse. It has very low overhead (<1%) since it piggybacks on the data the JVM is  gathering anyway.

It's very easy to use and it can also give a lot information you typically won't find in other profiling tools, e.g. latency profiling, online memory inspection, detailed gc statistics

Answer (score 3):

Consider cutting-edge https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler

> This project is a low overhead sampling profiler for Java that does not suffer from [Safepoint bias problem](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.ru/2016/02/why-most-sampling-java-profilers-are.html). It features HotSpot-specific APIs to collect stack traces and to track memory allocations. The profiler works with OpenJDK, Oracle JDK and other Java runtimes based on HotSpot JVM.

It's also built-in into IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cpu-profiler.html.

---

There is also similar https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/honest-profiler.

The comparison between `async-profiler` and `honest-profiler`: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/issues/77

Comment: Nice illustrated article on async-profiler: https://hackernoon.com/profiling-java-applications-with-async-profiler-049s2790

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266373/one-could-use-a-profiler-but-why-not-just-halt-the-program/317160#317160) is quick, dirty, and very effective: just take a few thread dumps, or pause the program several times, and look at the stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

[JVM Monitor](http://jvmmonitor.org/index.html) is a Java profiler integrated with Eclipse to monitor CPU, threads and memory usage of Java applications.

If further deep analysis is needed, you may use other tools (e.g. [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/), [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)) as a next step.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans IDE includes a free profiler.

Also, if I remember correctly, the academic license for JProfiler is (relatively) inexpensive.

Comment: OP did ask for "not too expensive academic licence". A single academic licence for JProfiler is US$199

Comment: He asked for something that was open source or had an inexpensive academic license.  In my opinion, US$199 is fairly inexpensive for a tool that costs $499 for a normal license.