# profile java code

Tags: java, c, optimization, profiling

I need to profile my JAVA SRC code for some particular problem I am currently working on. I've been using the trial version of a tool called [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).

I'd like to learn of some good community open-source tools, if available; other than that I am also looking forward to learn of some standard techniques that are widely adopted (or must know).

For C Code optimization I use VALGRIND; please also let me know of good tools available on Windows.

Comment: Do at least a minimal research! the answer from @afk could have come straight from your google experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 1.6 comes with a rudimentary profiler: `jvisualvm`. It is in the same directory as `java` and `javac`.

Comment: The visualvm tool comes only with the JDK (not the JRE) and was added in Jave 6 update 07 - it wasn't present in the original Java 6 release.

Comment: I think VisualVM is only available since update 7 (or was it 10). But other than that it's has a very nice ease-of-use/usefullnes ratio. Also: it's available as a standalone application as well: https://visualvm.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at the answers to this question: [open source java profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948549/open-source-java-profilers)

Answer (score 3):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) has a pretty decent Java profiler built in.

Comment: The NetBeans profile is actually related to jvisualvm (the tool suggested by SingleShot). I'm not sure which one is a derivative of the other, however.

Comment: The profiling component of visualvm was originally developed as part of netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

While not OpenSource, I personally really like [YourKit](http://yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp) - it has great visualization and is really easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

The "jvisualvm" tool in the latest Java 6 JDK contains a profiler (from Netbeans) and can attach to an already running program, making it very simple to do initial investigations.

Answer (score 1):

[JRockit Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/jrockit/index.html), it's not open source, but it's a commercial profiler you're free to use for development. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jrockit/missioncontrol/new_and_noteworthy/3.1.0/index.html) you can read what's new in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly [Eclipse TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) can attach its profiler to Java process but I could never manage to get it work nicely. NetBeans Profiler is by far the easiest to attach to external processes.

Once you have your profiling data or heap dump, my choice of poison is [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to do the analysis.

Comment: Yeah, TPTP is horribly difficult to set up and use. Also incredibly slow.

Comment: Though I had some issues with the setup, I had success using "Eclipse TPTP" to profile Java code and I found its analysis to be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the tools are open source, but you can find a listing of all the available tools at http://javatoolbox.com/categories/profiling-debugging

Each tool is referenced with a short description of what it proposes.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Jrat a lot for Java profiling: http://jrat.sourceforge.net/

Free open source C memory leak (and other detector) that works in Windows: duma (http://duma.sourceforge.net/). It's not as easy to use as Valgrind (you need to edit your sources and it doesn't have that nifty "do not report this" option - i've not found it yet anyway). The like-Valgrind options for Windows are all commercial (IBM's Purify seems the best but the license is quite pricy)

I do C optimization on windows using the gcc tools, gcov I think is what is used for profiling (might be wrong, haven't used it in a while)

Answer (score 0):

[Try taking "stackshots".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) It's the *no-profiler alternative*.

It's not just another pretty face, but it gets results.