# Running Visual VM from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, profiler, visualvm

I am trying to debug a java app using Visual VM in Eclipse kepler. I am executing the class having main method selecting Visual VM as launcher. I have configured Visual VM as per the instructions given in http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/05/setting-up-visualvm-in-under-5-minutes. I am getting the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: “Launching TestNew”.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

“TestNew” is the name of the class with main method I am trying to execute.

please help.

Comment: got the resolution. Had to set the jvisual.exe path in eclipse.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue... Let me expand a bit on Anushree's comment:

- Go to ***Window*** ⇒ ***Preferences*** ⇒ ***Run/Debug*** ⇒ ***Launching*** ⇒ ***VisualVM Configuration***
- ***Browse...*** for the ***VisualVM Executable*** in your JDK's bin-directory
- Make sure to also set the JDK's root directory under ***JDK Home***. If you leave that pointing to your JRE directory, you'll run into the next error...

Happy profiling...

BTW: If you then have issues getting your application to show up inside jVisualVM, take a look here:
[Getting Java program running in Eclipse to show up in VisualVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221821/getting-java-program-running-in-eclipse-to-show-up-in-visualvm)

Answer (score 1):

For Linux users :

1. Once visual vm launcher is intalled in eclipse , install visual vm in linux using command "sudo apt-get install -y visualvm".
2. On successfull installation , in terminal search for

> whereis visualvm

3. The search will give following responses :

> visualvm: /usr/bin/visualvm     /etc/visualvm    /usr/share/visualvm
> /usr/share/man/man1/visualvm.1.gz

4. In eclipse go to
   Window --> Preferences --> Run/Debug --> Launching --> VisualVM Configuration
5. copy the value "/usr/bin/visualvm" in the space and click on apply & close.