# Which one is indicating the exact memory use for java application

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a java application. The issue now I take a heap using the jmap and I also got this codes running in my application.Both are giving me different values. The runtime is showing out of `256mb` which is what I have assigned as initial and maximum memory? I want to detect is there any memory leakage but the runtime is fluctuating and whereas the one from heap is keep increasing in small amount? Any help on this?

```
long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
System.out.println("\n\nUsed memory is bytes: " + memory);

//Print the jvm heap size.
long heapSize = runtime.totalMemory();
System.out.println("\n\nHeap Size = " + heapSize);

int mb = 1024*1024;
System.out.println("##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####");

//Print used memory
System.out.println("Used Memory:" + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb);

//Print free memory
System.out.println("Free Memory:" + runtime.freeMemory() / mb);

//Print total available memory
System.out.println("Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory() / mb);

//Print Maximum available memory
System.out.println("Max Memory:" + runtime.maxMemory() / mb);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to watch memory usage etc.

Comment: I have problem using it tried many ways to link to my remote application but it failed so that that is why I revert to all this mechanism ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Visual VM tutorial on connecting to remote apps? http://visualvm.java.net/applications_remote.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you can try Netbeans profiler. You can profile your web/standalone applications using netbeans profiler.

We are uning netbeans profiler to profiling in our applications. Nice tool for profiling the java applications.

Check it out.

https://profiler.netbeans.org/

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqProfilerAttachRemoteServer

Comment: Is it possible for me not to mess with allow any permission stuff cause of security of the server. Cant I use the jmap instance to do a profiling?  What is your comment on that ?

Comment: You need the permission to execute sh file on server. So only you can use net-beans pro-filer. And need to open one port to profile binding through netbeans IDE.

Comment: What else must I install on it? How to bind the port for the profiling is it similar to Visual VM ?

Comment: I am not running any of the servers stated here http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqProfilerAttachRemoteServer mine is just a socket application.

Comment: Nothing else need to install. I never tried VisualVM. Using netbeans profiler i can profilie memory, cpu usage , delay to excute the methods and much more... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948549/open-source-java-profilers

Comment: install net-beans and click the profiler. Decide What you are going to profile CPU/memory and select remote/local. It will show the instructions you need to copy that one and follow that.

Comment: Ok thank let me do the downloading complete first then I will try and get back to you.

Comment: I am on centos platform so I have into the profile. I have clicked on the create a remote profiling it bring into a temp folder? Quite lost here

Comment: I follow the first link which says this instruction Choose Profile -> Profile Main Project ( Profile Main Project ) from the main menu. mine is not active and not able to click on it. Only active is the Attach Profiler