# Test Performance of a desktop application that doesn't use HTTP protocole

Tags: java, performance, load, desktop-application

Is there any way to test the performance of a desktop application that doesn't use HTTP protocol. it only upload and open some images and also doesn't connect to the internet. I tried Jmeter and Gatling but it doesn't work.

Comment: Define "performance".

Comment: What are the inputs and outputs of the application? In which format and how is the input made?

Comment: Run Java Mission Control (jmc) from your JDKs `bin` directory.

Comment: @SurfMan I just need to test CPU, RAM and time consumed during an action on this application

Comment: In that case you need a profiler. Here's a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948549/open-source-java-profilers

Comment: @SurfMan I tried Net Beans profiler but it can not record the steps and rerun it again

Answer (score 0):

*I know what you’re probably thinking. In general, the idea of performance testing of desktop applications is irrelevant, as normally desktop applications are assumed to have only one user. Furthermore, performance testing in this case is limited to application profiling, the process of application analysis using 3rd-party profiling tools and white-box source code testing, in order to identify algorithms which are inefficient, overly large and/or non optimal structures and collections, and to test individual functions, execution time, and associated resource costs, etc.*

[Refer to this article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter)

Comment: I already read this before but Jmeter records HTTP and HTTPS flow while my application is a simple application that upload some CT scan images and make some modifications on it without using any APIs or requests