# How to do spring batch application performance analysis and tuning in Intellij?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-batch, profiling, azure-aks

I have a Spring batch application that runs in the VM, it takes 2 hours to process 10k records.

We are planning to migrate the application to Azure kubernetes and I see that the migrated application takes 6 hours.

I need to make the necessary changes to meet the current performance.

We didn't make any major changes in the code.

How do I do profiling to analysis the performance issues in Intellij? Is there any other way to find the cause for the performance impact.

Note : I don't have appDynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not really specific to Spring Batch per se, but if you want to profile a Java application with IntelliJ IDEA, you can run the app from within the IDE (or outside the IDE) and attach a profiler to it, see [Profiling tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cpu-profiler.html). This feature is only available in IntelliJ IDEA ultimate edition.

There are open source profilers that you can use as well, see [Open Source Java Profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948549/open-source-java-profilers).