# Spring Batch : How to identify the java method and SQL queries that causes performance degradation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application that runs for hours (~10hrs) in existing on-premise environment, we are in the progress of migrating & deploying the application into AKS.

The same application takes ~20hrs to execute in the AKS environment.

We want to identify the java method and SQL queries that causes performance degradation? How do I approach?

**Note:** as mentioned in [How to do spring batch application performance analysis and tuning in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201869/how-to-do-spring-batch-application-performance-analysis-and-tuning-in-intellij)  , I am trying to run the application iwth profiler.

Comment: If mysql then setup and check slow query log

Comment: you mean enable the profiling in mysql ? can you help me with a reference article?

Comment: its better to use an APM like pinpoint or elastic APM for monitoring end to end transaction. you could easily find out where is the problem. But it need additional time to setup and figure out things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer of the link you shared, profiling tools are the way to go.

In addition to that, since your application is based on Spring Batch, you can use the built-in support for Micrometer. This gives you some key metrics about your job execution like the duration of the job, the duration of each step, etc. Please refer to the [Monitoring and metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/monitoring-and-metrics.html#monitoring-and-metrics) section of the documentation for more details.