# Profiling a Java Application in Eclipse? (plug-in)

Tags: java, eclipse, optimization, profiling, plugins

I'm looking to find bottlenecks in my Java application in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)). I'm thinking this might be useful:

http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=tptp.performance

Any other good plug-ins to use?

**EDIT** OK, it doesn't necessarily have to be an Eclipse plug-in. But it would be nice. And, I'm most interested in speed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you can, use [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) in the Sun Java 6 JDK (IBM too).  It works out of the box and can answer many of the initial questions.

Note that on Windows you need to invoke jvisualvm with the same Java binary as the program you want to investigate for best results.

(visualvm is a stand-alone subset of the Netbeans profiler)

Comment: There is an eclipse launcher for visualvm: http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html#installation

Comment: @Zitrax the link is outdated

Comment: https://visualvm.github.io/idesupport.html

Answer (score 21):

In my experience, TPTP is something to run away from as fast as possible. It's a horribly overengineered mess, almost impossible to get to work, badly documented, and slow as molasses.

I'm not aware of any good and free profiling plugins for eclipse. But then, does it really have to be an eclipse plugin? [VisualVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) comes with the JDK since Java 6u7, is fast and easy to use. It may not be the most feature-rich of profilers, but has been sufficient for me.

Comment: Seconded, avoid TPTP at all costs.

Comment: Yet another one of IBMs projects for their proprietary products based on Eclipse which has been polished up and migrated to core Eclipse.  Sigh.

Comment: The TPTP project now seems moribund: "participation in the project has dwindled over time", "in maintenance mode", to be archived: http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm

Comment: Profiling is one of the things that Netbeans does much, much better than Eclipse.

Answer (score 11):

[YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) is an excellent commercial profiler that has good [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) integration.

Answer (score 7):

I found [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) (commercial) to be really helpful. It has Eclipse integration, although it is not an Eclipse plugin per sa', so you can very easily invoke a profiler instead of a regular execution session. It had very good bottleneck analysis and you can find-tune the settings to lower the overheads of the profiler itself. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 6):

I've also used the [Netbeans profiler](https://profiler.netbeans.org/) which is pretty good.  It's pretty easy to set it up to profile your Eclipse project while it is running in Eclipse.  You don't need to open the project in Netbeans.

Comment: NetBeans 8.2, and its ["hidden" calibration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198758/netbeans-jdk-calibration-8-1), worked great thx!

Answer (score 4):

The [Eclipse Memory Analyser](http://eclipse.org/mat/) has been helping me a lot recently.

Comment: This repository link isn't working for me:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/mat/0.7/update-site/

Comment: Profiler != Heap analyzer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a IBM JDK equivalent for visualvm, try the IBM Java Health Center: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/healthcenter/. It has some decent profiling capabilities, and is rather fast.

Answer (score 0):

[You can always dump call stacks (e.g. Ctrl-Break on command line).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266373/one-could-use-a-profiler-but-why-not-just-halt-the-program/317160#317160) It is surprisingly very effective.