# Eclipse plugin that can check which part of code is taking too much time?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am completely new to code analysis. I want to know if there is an easy to use analysis tool or plugin for eclipse that will analyze my java code.

The problem is my java swing program is taking too much time, because I manually did many graphical programming.

For example, I have a list of images that are displayed dynamically, on top of each other (like layers in Photoshop). Each of them will respond to user movements, so I have to update the images each time the user triggers a change.

However, after adding some features (such as ColorOP, RescaleOP, etc.), the program started to lag. Now, I want to know which part of the code is inefficient and taking too much time, so that I can find better alternatives. Is there a tool for such purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580091/profiling-a-java-application-in-eclipse-plug-in

Answer (score 0):

Visual Performance Analysier is an open source tool from IBM, which can visualize performance profiling of Java program well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Java profiler, I generally prefer [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/).