# How to get the running time of Java plugins using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Now I am using a plugin based Java to put into a third party software (ImageJ) to process images. After inputting images, it shows the GUI where I can choose the segmentation parameters and tracking parameters. But it runs slowly after setting parameters on the GUI. Hence, I want to know which part(Segmentation or Tracking) makes the Java code run slowly.If I use Eclipse, can I get the running time of each part and how I can get it because it's a plugin and the running time will be different if I change the parameters on the GUI and input images. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect situation for a profiler. I have not tried attaching one to Eclipse itself, however, so I cannot provide a full answer. But I would recommend checking that out.

Comment: Maybe take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580091/profiling-a-java-application-in-eclipse-plug-in