# Netbeans JDK Calibration 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling

How to do JDK calibration using Netbeans 8.1. I've googled some and found this link [here](https://profiler.netbeans.org/docs/help/5.5/calibration.html).

> It says "choose Profile > Advanced Commands > Run Profiler Calibration
>   from the main menu

But I can't find it, there is no Advance Commands in my menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was very simple. It goes like 
Tools > Options > Java > Profiler > General > Manage Calibration Data

Comment: ... Profiler > General > Manage Calibration Data

Comment: @AquariusPower are you sure about > General > ?

Comment: oh.. I am using 8.2! have no idea how 8.1 looks like!