# Profiling a Java Web Start application

Tags: java, profiling, java-web-start

There are a lot of java profilers out there, any recommendations as to what would be best for profiling a java web start application that is being deployed to glassfish inside a war?

Comment: What are you looking to profile?  Memory, cpu time, object allocation, etc, this will help to narrow down what tools(free or otherwise) may be available.

Comment: I think in my context, it would make more sense to focus on memory usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the traditional answers for such a question are [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) and/or [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/) (if you have money).

If you go for VisualVM, [this thread](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=311717) will help you to configure your Webstart application for JMX.

If you go for Yourkit, have a look at [this discussion](http://forums.yourkit.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23).

Comment: You don't need JMX to run for visualvm to be able to connect if running on the same machine, only across the network.

Comment: I actually used the VisualVM tool that is packaged with the JDK. It is in the bin directory and called jvisualvm.exe. When running the web start application with java6, you have to turn off class sharing. I used the following command line to get it to work correctly with visualvm

    javaws -J-Xshare:off app.jnlp

otherwise visualvm will crash.

Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: @Casey Thanks for the Xshare flag tip! My web start application was not showing up in VisualVM on Linux. Starting the web start app with the Xshare:off flag fixed this problem!

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266373/one-could-use-a-profiler-but-why-not-just-halt-the-program/317160#317160) a quick-and-dirty but simple, free, and effective way.
It's language-agnostic, and the way it works is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).