# Beyond Profiling a Java Spring application with Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, profiling, spring-aop

It's possible to log profiling information thanks to spring aop. See this for example:
[Profiling a Java Spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475682/profiling-a-java-spring-application)

Now what it produces is a log file with lines and lines of 'enter method @...' 'leave method @...'. It may be a bit cumbersome to skim through for a simple human brain.

Do you know of any tool to digest these files, to ease navigation in the results, possibly to create nice graphs?

Comment: Sounds like you should just try a regular profiling tool instead as it gives a good overview of which classes/routines are most cpu/mem intensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Spring Insight](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/devedition/cinintro.html)