# Profile Spring application context loading

Tags: java, spring

How to profile Spring application context loading?

Is there a way to profile the spring application context loading (except of putting the spring logs in DEBUG mode. Tried it already, I need something more fine grained)?
In our application this takes long time, and I want to understand what are the reasons.

I already use the

```
context.setValidating(false); 
context.refresh(); // Load the context.
```

in order not to validate the XML schema of the spring xml files of beans definitions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Profiling a Java Spring application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475682/profiling-a-java-spring-application)

Comment: @sheltem - read the post. I don't think this is a duplicate. I am interested not in profiling the ongoing application using Spring, but only the application context loading. It takes too long time to load the context. All the rest works fine.

Comment: Must be loading a lot of beans.

Comment: By a quick look at source: `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry#beforeSingletonCreation` and `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry#afterSingletonCreation` might be good spots for the profiling logic.

Comment: You should be able to pin point the problem just from the DEBUG logs. Look for some delays between log messages about bean creation.