# Java Profiling Tool for Linux

Tags: java, linux

I want to run a java program on a linux server in profiling mode.

Is there any profiling tool that can profile a java program on a Linux server in command prompt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All these  Java profiling tools can be used in Linux:

- [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/)
- [JProfiler](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Quality-Assurance-and-Testing/JProfiler-21389.shtml)
- [HPROF](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) (Java 5+)
- [JRat](http://jrat.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Sunil, HPROF and JRat are command-line tools. The other ones  - as far as I know - are GUI only. But all these tools can all profile GUI and command-line applications.

Answer (score 7):

JVisualVM is a very basic profiling tool that comes with the official JDK from Sun.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html

EDIT: Also see .....

[Any recommended Java profiling tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422289/any-recommended-java-profiling-tutorial)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler

Answer (score 4):

http://profiler.netbeans.org/

> **Profiler**
>
> NetBeans profiler is a module to
>   provide a full-featured profiling
>   functionality for the NetBeans IDE.
>   The profiling functions include CPU,
>   memory and threads profiling as well
>   as basic JVM monitoring, allowing
>   developers to be more productive in
>   solving memory or performance-related
>   issues.

Answer (score 1):

[InMemProfiler](http://wiki.github.com/mchr3k/org.inmemprofiler/) can be used at the command line to profile memory allocations. Live vs collected allocations can be tracked and collected objects can be split into buckets based on their lifetimes.

In trace mode this tool can be used to [identify the source of memory allocations](http://wiki.github.com/mchr3k/org.inmemprofiler/identifying-memory-allocators).