# Monitor distribution of execution time of a java program

Tags: java, profiling

I have a very long program with hundreds of methods. In my attempt to enhance the performance of the program, I want to monitor the time taken in each method or for loop to see where should I start to optimize the code.

is there any eclipse plugin or software tool to do that? I mean to calculate time taken in each method without adding tons of lines of code?

Comment: There is something called appDynamics agent (limited free version), you may try that.

Comment: Take a [*look at this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2425217/23771). Basically the idea is to generalize the method you would use to find an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) has an excellent profiler.

I usually run my code in a hot loop and attach after the code warms up, but setting a breakpoint early in your code and then attaching works well also. Think you'll really like visualvm, I use it to track down the performance bottlenecks in code at least once a week.

Answer (score 0):

jvisualvm it is in jdk and jre AFAIR