# How to improve performance of a web system in java using netbeans profiler

Tags: java, performance, glassfish, profiling

We have a system on java that uses glassfish and because in some small pc the system goes slow we decide to use the netbeans profiler and it showed us the following information:

```
Threads: 91    
Loaded Classes: 14.186 (max)    
Total Memory: 282 MB    
Used Memory: 194 MB    
Time Spent in GC: 0%    
Surviving Generations: 79%    

Detail:    
Total bytes: 109.430.481    
Total classes: 14.603    
Total instances: 1.655.029    
Classloaders: 433    
GC roots: 3.757    
Number of objects pending for finalization: 0    

Environment:    
OS: Windows Vista (6.0) Service Pack 2    
Architecture: x86 32bit    
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre    
Java Version: 1.7.0_03    
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (22.1-b02, mixed mode)    
Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation    

Head Walker: (High Value)    
Class: String    
Instances: 237.083    
Instance size: 24    
Total size: 5.689.992    
Retained size: 22.755.966
```

the libraries that use our system are:

```
Struts 2.3.1    
Spring 3.0.6    
AspectJ 1.7.3    
Jasper Report 5.1    
Cors Filter    
Poi 3.7    
Itext 2.1.7    
Postgresql 9.1    
commons-lang 3-3.1   
commons-pool 1.5.5    
commons-dbcp 1.4
```

also we follow the string class in the memory chart and most memory consumption is in the classes that are using by Xwork (struts) and Aspectj libraries

our questions are:

1- How I can lower the CPU and memory consumption when most of the consumption is in the libraries?

2- What other speed improvements I can do on the system?

Comment: For your question 1, the way to reduce time consumption is to find ways to make fewer calls to the libraries. [*This discusses how to find out where they are.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2425217/23771) Then when you reduce time consumption, memory consumption usually goes down with it, because often much of the time consumption is in memory management.