# Frame-Rate / Performance drops over time

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am creating a simple pet simulator, it is my first project created for an assignment. Most of the functionality is working fine, I have re-written it many times as I have gotten better at setting out projects, however while adding in a timer I have encountered a massive floor.

After running the project my game seems to work fine, images are being rendered (Perhaps not the most efficiently) and my timer/FPS counter works well. However ever since I have added this timing/FPS code, it has been slowly getting slower and slower in FPS and then freezing up and crashing.

I followed Ninja Cave's timing tutorial for LWJGL. http://ninjacave.com/lwjglbasics4

Here is my source code, not all classes are included as there are quite a few, but can if need be. I have tried to just include the rendering focussed ones.

Main Class
http://pastebin.com/BpkHHnnj

Rendering Class
http://pastebin.com/QtJeYw1a

Texture Loader Class
http://pastebin.com/RX5iDXQm

Main Game State Class
http://pastebin.com/pvgDLkeM

The Pet Class
http://pastebin.com/VF6cq9S4

Thanks

Comment: You need to profile your application in order to determine where the bottlenecks are.  [Here is a profiling overview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2425217/1827903)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently working on *fixing* your issue, but your `renderer.readyTexture()` just spins wildly out of control, and is essentially leaking memory, and **fast**, which explains the drop in speed.

**Edit**: I got the memory usage to stabilize.

Add `public Map<String, Texture> loadedTextures = new HashMap<String, Texture>();` to your `renderer` class in render.java and change your `renderer.readyTexture()` method to this:

```
    public void readyTexture(String textureDir){
        if (!loadedTextures.containsKey(textureDir) || loadedTextures.get(textureDir) == null) {
            texture = lt.loadTexture(textureDir);
            loadedTextures.put(textureDir, texture);
        } else {
            texture = loadedTextures.get(textureDir);
        }

        textureDirString = textureDir;
        texture.bind();
        texLoaded = true;
        System.out.println("Loaded: " + textureDirString);
    }
```

Now that you have the code, the `Map/HashMap` stores the already loaded textures. In the `renderer.readyTexture()` method, I have it check if the `Map` does not contain the key `textureDir` and if it does, I check to see if it is null. If the entry is not in the `Map` or the contained `Texture` is `null`, we load the texture, and store it in the map. If the texture is stored, we pull it out from the `Map` and bind it.

Before, you were loading up the image every time, and the garbage collector was **not** removing it, this is possibly an issue with Slick, but if you cache everything properly, it works just fine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for better resource management. Thus can also occur when creating lots of short lived objects repeatedly

Comment: The reason behind this isn't Slicks fault - Slick is loading up a new texture into memory every time. It's doing exactly what you asked.

You need a resource manager that does smart loading and can hopefully unload smartly.

Comment: Robbie, you solved it :). A couple of days ago I tried to fix the loading of textures repetitively, but forgot about it when it did not work. Thanks for this knowledge on Maps and HashMaps, more reading to do :) They seem very useful.

Comment: You are very welcome. Another thing is that at a passing glance over slick, I could not figure out a way to release the resources being used by the slick `Texture` (Note: `Texture.release()` did **not** work for me), so I recommend looking that up if you intend on releasing any resources before your program closes.

Comment: Awesome will look into that, also since youve had a look at my code, do you know why I cant render multiple of one quad in a for loop....

`rend.readyTexture("health");
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   
   rend.tileRender(heartX + XOffset,heartY);
  }`