# Profiling Python script from shell environment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm profiling a Python 3.4 script within an interactive shell environment (IDE, if it matters). Normally I use `cProfile` to profile functions. However, this time I have some top-level code in the script. By "top-level" I mean that the code is not inside a function definition. `cProfile.run` won't accept the filename - normally I would pass it a function.

To get around this, I wrap the top-level code in a `main()` function, execute it to create `main` in the shell namespace, then run `cProfiler.run('main()')`. This is pretty annoying - I would like to fool around with several variables generated in the top-level code, and I'd rather not try to return them all from `main()`.

I have carefully read the similar questions [How can you profile a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) and [How to profile my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045556/how-to-profile-my-code).
They give great solutions for profiling top-level code from the command line and for profiling functions from a shell, but I don't think they address this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I have a kluge for getting this done, but I think there's probably a better way out there.

```
cProfile.run(compile(open(filename, "rb").read(), filename, 'exec'))
```

where `filename` is the filename of the script.

Comment: I removed your disclaimer since it's not really important to answer the question. It might be better as a comment on the question.

Comment: @AdamSmith OK, thanks - I haven't ever answered my own question before. Repeated for anyone who cares: since I've answered my own question here, I will not upvote or accept my own answer.