# Best method to measure execution time of a python snippet

Tags: python, time, timeit

I want to compare execution time of two snippets and see which one is faster. So, I want an accurate method to measure execution time of my python snippets.

I already tried using `time.time()`, `time.process_time()`, `time.perf_counter_ns()` as well as `timeit.timeit()`, but I am facing the same issues with all of the them. That is: when I use any of the above methods to measure execution time of THE SAME snippet, it returns a different value each time I run it. And this variation is somewhat significant, to the extent that I cannot reliably use them to compare difference in execution time of two snippets.

As an example, I am running following code in my google colab:

```
import time
t1 = time.perf_counter()
sample_list = []
for i in range(1000000):
  sample_list.append(i)
t2 = time.perf_counter()
print(t2 - t1)
```

I ran above code 10 times and the variation in my results is about 50% (min value = 0.14, max value = 0.28).

Any alternatives?

Comment: `timeit` runs the snippet many times (default 1 million). If its a CPU bound bit of code, it should be similar across runs. I notice drift of < 10%. If doing I/O, that's a different story. Do you have an example we could try?

Comment: The term you're looking for is _profiling_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script

Comment: I added an example I am running right now.

Comment: Google colab is a confounding factor. You are running on a server with many collaborators. Performance analysis should be done in as tightly controlled environment as possible. Even a laptop that may vary clock speed could be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The execution time of a given code snippet will almost always be different every time you run it.  Most tools that are available for profiling a single function/snippet of code take this into account, and run the code multiple times to be able to provide an average execution time.  The reason for this is that there are other processes running on your computer, and resources are not always allocated the same way, so it is impossible to control every variable so that you get the same execution time for every run.

One of the easiest ways to profile a given function or short snippet of code is using the [`%timeit` "magic" command in ipython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit).  Example:

```py
>>> %timeit 1 + 1
8.41 ns ± 0.0181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)
```

It also allows you to enter a multi-line block of code to time if you use `%%timeit` instead of `%timeit`.

The [timeit library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) can be used independently, but it is often easier to use in an interactive ipython session.

Additional resources:

- [How to profile my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045556/how-to-profile-my-code)
- [What is %timeit in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280470/what-is-timeit-in-python)
- [How can I time a code segment for testing performance with Pythons timeit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866380/how-can-i-time-a-code-segment-for-testing-performance-with-pythons-timeit)

Comment: timeit also gives different results under the same condition (the same snippet run for the same number of times). If there is not a robust method to measure execution time of a snippet, how do we really want to prove if one code is faster than the other when optimizing things? I remember a youtube video comparing execution time of a factorial function when calculated based on recursion vs. loops. The youtuber used time.time() method and concluded loop is faster. Then I tried on my system and found recursion was faster.

Comment: If there is not a statistically significant difference between the run times returned by `timeit` for 2 different implementations that accomplish the same goal, then you should just go with the one that is more readable / clearer.  Differences in Python version and where you run a given program can result in some differences that you will never eliminate entirely.  This is true of any programming language.

Comment: Additionally, `time.time()` should not be used to measure execution time for anything.  It is not guaranteed to result in accurate values in the case of leap seconds and similar.  It is better to use `time.montotonic()` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I read somewhere that disabling the garbage collection also helps increasing the accuracy of execution time measurement.