# Processing: How can I improve the framerate in my program?

Tags: optimization, processing

So I've been working in [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) for a few weeks now, and, though I'm not experienced in programming, I have moved on to more complex projects. I'm programming an evolution simulator, that spawns creatures with random properties.

Eventually, I'll add reproduction, but as of now the creatures just sort of float around the screen, and follow the mouse somewhat. It interacts with sound from the line in, but I commented those parts out so that it can be viewed on the canvas, it shouldn't really change the question, I just thought I would point it out.

As of now, the framerate is far less than ideal for me, and it slowly lowers as more creatures are spawned. Am I making some fundamental mistake, or am I just running too many functions per frame?

Here's the source code, and you can play with it in the browser [here](http://processingtogether.com/sp/pad/export/ro.iSsfG8u3J13/rev.2):

```java
//import ddf.minim.*;
//import ddf.minim.signals.*;
//import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
//import ddf.minim.effects.*;

//Minim minim;
//AudioInput in;
boolean newCreature = true;
boolean matured[];
int ellipses[];
int hair[];
int maxCreatureNumber = 75;
//int volume;
//int volumeTolerance = 1;
int creatureIndex = -1;
int creatureX[];
int creatureY[];
float strokeWeightAttribute[];
float creatureSize[];
float creatureEndSize[];
float creatureXIncrement[];
float creatureYIncrement[];
float bubbleSize;
float easing = 0.05;
float angle = 0.00;
color colorAttribute[];

void setup() {
    background(0);
    size(1000,500);
    noFill();
    //minim = new Minim(this);
    //in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 512);
    creatureX = new int[maxCreatureNumber];
    creatureY = new int[maxCreatureNumber];
    ellipses = new int[maxCreatureNumber];
    hair = new int[maxCreatureNumber];
    strokeWeightAttribute = new float[maxCreatureNumber];
    creatureEndSize = new float[maxCreatureNumber];
    creatureSize = new float[maxCreatureNumber];
    creatureXIncrement = new float[maxCreatureNumber];
    creatureYIncrement = new float[maxCreatureNumber];
    matured = new boolean[maxCreatureNumber];
    colorAttribute = new color[maxCreatureNumber];
}

void draw() {
  angle += 0.05;
  fill(0, 50);
  rect(-1, -1, 1001, 501);
  // for(int i = 0; i < in.bufferSize() - 1; i++) {
  //     if(in.mix.get(i) * 50 > volumeTolerance) {
  //         volume++;
  //     }
  // }
  if(newCreature && creatureIndex < maxCreatureNumber - 1) {
      initSpontaneousCreature();
  }
  updateCreatures();
  // bubbleSize = volume/250;
  bubbleSize += 0.01;
  // volume = 0;
}

//void stop() {
//    minim.stop();
//    super.stop();
//}

void initSpontaneousCreature() {
    creatureIndex++;
    creatureEndSize[creatureIndex] = int(random(5, 20));
    creatureX[creatureIndex] = int(random(1000));
    if(creatureX[creatureIndex] >= 500) {
        creatureX[creatureIndex] -= creatureEndSize[creatureIndex];
    }
    else {
        creatureX[creatureIndex] += creatureEndSize[creatureIndex];
    }
    creatureY[creatureIndex] = int(random(500));
    if(creatureY[creatureIndex] >= 250) {
        creatureY[creatureIndex] -= creatureEndSize[creatureIndex];
    }
    else {
        creatureY[creatureIndex] += creatureEndSize[creatureIndex];
    }
    ellipses[creatureIndex] = int(random(4));
    hair[creatureIndex] = int(random(4));
    strokeWeightAttribute[creatureIndex] = random(1, 4);
    colorAttribute[creatureIndex] = color(int(random(20,255)), int(random(20,255)), int(random(20,255)));
    matured[creatureIndex] = false;
    newCreature = false;
    while(ellipses[creatureIndex] == 0 && hair[creatureIndex] == 0) {
        ellipses[creatureIndex] = int(random(4));
        hair[creatureIndex] = int(random(4));
    }
}

void updateCreatures() {
    for(int n = 0; n <= creatureIndex; n++) {
        if(matured[n]) {
            creatureX[n] += ((((mouseX) - creatureX[n]) * easing) / (60/*-abs(volume/5))*/)) + random(-5, 6);
            creatureY[n] += ((((mouseY) -creatureY[n]) * easing) / (60/*-abs(/*volume/5))*/)) + random(-5,6);
            drawCreature();
        }
        else {
            if(creatureEndSize[n] != creatureSize[n]) {
                creatureSize[n] += bubbleSize;
                if(creatureSize[n] > creatureEndSize[n]) {
                    creatureSize[n] -= (creatureSize[n] - creatureEndSize[n]);
                }
            }
            else {
                newCreature = true;
                matured[n] = true;
                // bubbleSize = 0;
            }
            drawCreature();
        }
    }
}

void drawCreature() {
    for(int n = 0; n <= creatureIndex; n++) {
        if(matured[n]) {
            stroke(colorAttribute[n]);
            strokeWeight(strokeWeightAttribute[n]);
            for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                if(ellipses[n] == i) {
                    if(i == 0) {

                    }
                    else if (i == 1) {
                      pushMatrix();
                      translate(creatureX[n], creatureY[n]);
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      rotate(radians(180));
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      popMatrix();
                    }
                    else if(i == 2) {
                      pushMatrix();
                      translate(creatureX[n], creatureY[n]);
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      rotate(radians(180));
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      rotate(radians(270));
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      popMatrix();

                    }
                    else if(i == 3) {
                      pushMatrix();
                      translate(creatureX[n], creatureY[n]);
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      rotate(radians(90));
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      rotate(radians(180));
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      rotate(radians(270));
                      ellipse(creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n], creatureSize[n]);
                      popMatrix();
                    }
                }
                if(hair[n] == i) {
                    if(i == 0) {

                    }
                    else if (i == 1) {
                        pushMatrix();
                        translate(creatureX[n], creatureY[n]);
                        for(int j = 0; j <= 360; j+=70) {
                            rotate(j);
                            stroke(colorAttribute[n], random(255));
                            line(0,0, creatureSize[n] + random(10), creatureSize[n] + random(10));
                        }
                        popMatrix();
                    }
                    else if(i == 2) {
                        pushMatrix();
                        translate(creatureX[n], creatureY[n]);
                        for(int j = 0; j <= 360; j+=30) {
                            rotate(j);
                            stroke(colorAttribute[n], random(255));
                            line(0,0, creatureSize[n] + random(10), creatureSize[n] + random(10));
                        }
                        popMatrix();
                    }
                    else if(i == 3) {
                        pushMatrix();
                        translate(creatureX[n], creatureY[n]);
                        for(int j = 0; j <= 360; j+=1) {
                            rotate(j);
                            stroke(colorAttribute[n], random(255));
                            line(0,0, creatureSize[n] + random(10), creatureSize[n] + random(10));
                        }
                        popMatrix();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(!matured[n]) {
            stroke(abs(sin(angle) * 255));
            //strokeWeight(5);
            ellipse(creatureX[n], creatureY[n], creatureSize[n] * 5,  creatureSize[n] * 5);
            noStroke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Profile your app, see which parts are slow, and optimize them.

Comment: Not sure I understand, you mean isolate each section?

Comment: Yes. Take individual sections of the code and measure their time. Once you find the expensive ones, break them down further, until you see what's really slow. That's what you need to focus on.

Comment: On a first stab, I'd say the creature states with 'hair' are slowing you down a bit: in drawCreature(), where you check if i==2 and i==3... for(int j = 0; j <= 360; j+=1) and  for(int j = 0; j <= 360; j+=30)...also, you use pushMatrix(), popMatrix() a lot...I'll dig deeper and see what might be the main culprit in this thick code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right, as I suspected, all the unnecessary `pushMatrix()`, `popMatrix()` calls and the large amount of lines seemed to be the main culprits, still, there was a lot of redundant code.

I simply refactored the code in a cleaner manner and it seems to run fine.
Here is my 'improved' version:

```
int maxCreatures = 75;
int numCreatures = 0;
int spawnNthFrame = 50;//spawn a creature every 50 frames
Creature[] creatures;

void setup() {
  background(0);
  size(1000,500);
  noFill();
  creatures = new Creature[maxCreatures];
}

void draw() {
  fill(0, 50);
  rect(-1, -1, 1001, 501);
  if(frameCount % spawnNthFrame == 0){
    println("creatures: " + numCreatures);
    if(numCreatures < maxCreatures) {
      //Creature constructor float endSize,int x, int y,int ellipses,int hair,float strokeW,color c
      creatures[numCreatures] = new Creature(random(5, 20),int(random(1000)),int(random(500)),int(random(4)),int(random(4)),random(1, 4),color(int(random(20,255)), int(random(20,255)), int(random(20,255))));
      numCreatures++;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < numCreatures; i++) creatures[i].update();
}
```

and the Creature class:

```
class Creature{
 int x,y,cXInc,cYInc;//if x,y are ints, increments would be into, right?
 float cStrokeWeight,cSize,cEndSize,cSizeInc = 0.01,easing = 0.05,angle = 0.00;
 color cColor;
 int hair,numHair,ellipses;
 boolean matured = false;

 Creature(float endSize,int x, int y,int ellipses,int hair,float strokeW,color c){
    cEndSize = endSize;
    this.x = x;
    if(x >= 500) x -= cEndSize;
    else         x += cEndSize;
    this.y = y;
    if(y >= 250) x -= cEndSize;
    else         x += cEndSize;
    this.ellipses = ellipses;
    this.hair = hair;
    if(hair == 1) numHair = 3;//~5, half that, draw through centre, etc.
    if(hair == 2) numHair = 6;
    if(hair == 3) numHair = 30;//no default value
    cStrokeWeight = strokeW;
    this.cColor = c;
 }
 void update(){
   if(matured) { 
    x += (((mouseX - x) * easing) / 60) + random(-5, 6);
    y += (((mouseY - y) * easing) / 60) + random(-5, 6);
   }else {
    if(cSize < cEndSize) cSize += cSizeInc;
    else matured = true;
    angle += 0.05;
   } 
   this.draw();
 }
 void draw(){
   if(matured){
     stroke(cColor);
     strokeWeight(cStrokeWeight);
     if(ellipses == 1){//2 ellipses diagonally
       ellipse(x,y,cSize,cSize);
       ellipse(x+cSize,y+cSize,cSize,cSize);
     }
     if(ellipses == 2){
       ellipse(x,y,cSize,cSize);
       ellipse(x,y+cSize,cSize,cSize);
       ellipse(x+cSize,y+cSize,cSize,cSize);
     }
     if(ellipses == 3){
       ellipse(x,y,cSize,cSize);
       ellipse(x+cSize,y,cSize,cSize);
       ellipse(x,y+cSize,cSize,cSize);
       ellipse(x+cSize,y+cSize,cSize,cSize);
     }
     float hairAngleInc = TWO_PI/numHair;//angle increment for each piece = 360/number of hair lines
     float hairAngle,hairLength,hairCos,hairSin;
     for(int i = 0; i < numHair; i++){
       hairAngle = hairAngleInc * i;
       hairCos = cos(hairAngle);
       hairSin = sin(hairAngle);
       hairLength = random(20);
       stroke(cColor, random(255));
       line(x + (hairCos * -hairLength),y + (hairSin * -hairLength), x + (hairCos * hairLength),y + (hairSin * hairLength)); 
     }
   }else{
     stroke(abs(sin(angle) * 255));
     ellipse(x,y, cSize * 5,  cSize * 5);
   }
 }
}
```

Ok, now for the explanations.

First, I separated all the variables that were related to one creature from the 'global' ones that determine how the sketch runs (how many creatures get spawned, etc.).

This makes the main code about 25 lines long and altogether a bit below 100 lines which is less than half of the original.

The first part doesn't do anything special. In the **draw()** function, instead of creating a Creature every frame, I draw one every Nth frame using the **spawnNthFrame** variable, this made it easy to see which state of the creature made it slow. If you set a small number like 2 to that variable it should spawn a lot of creatures per frame.

The Creature class has all the properties the original code stored in arrays.

Instead of doing

```
pushMatrix();
translate();
ellipse();
rotate()
ellipse()
popMatrix();
```

I simply draw the ellipses at x,y.
A little hint on the rotations. I've noticed they were increments
of 90 degrees. *Processing* has some nice constants for **90,180,360** degrees
in radians: **HALF_PI, PI, TWO_PI** which can be handy sometimes.

Now for the 'hairy' situation, here's something I commented out for myself:

```
//if(i == 1) for(int j = 0; j <= 360; j+=70) , well 360/70 is about 5, if (i == 2) , 12 hair
//if = 3-> 360 lines ? do you really need that many lines, that thick ? how about 30 ? 5*12=60, but if you draw the lines through the centre, not from the centre, you can get away with half the lines
```

So there were 3 loops for drawing lines, each having different increments. Basically 
there were either 360/70 lines, 360/30 lines and 360 lines. 
Roughly about 5,12 and 360 lines. About the 5,12 lines, I kind of halved that by drawing 'diameter' lines across the centre as opposed to 'radius' lines from the centre.

Here's what I mean,
[image: halfLines]

Also I think that 360 lines with that strokeWeight and the jittery motion will probably look like a bunch of lines hard to count, so I thought, why split hairs? :P

Maybe the creature will look pretty similar with about 60 radii which means 30 diameters.

Now to explain a bit of the trig functions used for this.
The main thing is the 'polar to cartesian' coordinates conversion:

Polar would be something like:

"I am moving on a circle to a direction described by an **angle** (much like one handle of a clock) and **radius** (distance from centre)."

and Cartesian

"I'm moving based on two **axes** (horizontal/X and vertical/Y), kind of like the streets of Manhattan, but I cheat and also move diagonally through walls."

If that makes any sense... :)
Anyway, you convert the **angle and radius** pair to the **x and y** pair using the formula:

```
x = cos(angle) * radius
y = sin(angle) * radius
```

For each line:

```
angle = hairAngle
radius = hairLength
```

So the **line()** with *x + (hairCos * -hairLength)* looks a bit like this:

```
x + (hairCos * -hairLength) = 
move to x and from there move by hairLength
to the left(-) for the current angle (hairCos)
```

Similar for y, but using cos, so this puts the first point of the line in the opposite direct (-hairLength) of the angle moving from the centre (which is the Creature's x) and the second is 'diagonal'. Imagine drawing 'diagonals' (from (-x,-y) to (+x,+y)), but you also rotate these.

**Update**

Apparently copy/pasting this code [works in javascript](http://hascanvas.com/creatures) too (best viewed in Chromium/Chrome). You can also run it right here:

```js
var maxCreatures = 75;
var numCreatures = 0;
var spawnNthFrame = 50;//spawn a creature every 50 frames
var creatures = [];

function setup() {
  background(0);
  createCanvas(1000,500);
  noFill();
}

function draw() {
  fill(0, 50);
  rect(-1, -1, 1001, 501);
  if(frameCount % spawnNthFrame === 0){
    println("creatures: " + numCreatures);
    if(numCreatures < maxCreatures) {
      //Creature constructor float endSize,int x, int y,int ellipses,int hair,float strokeW,color c
      creatures[numCreatures] = new Creature(random(5, 20),int(random(1000)),int(random(500)),int(random(4)),int(random(4)),random(1, 4),color(int(random(20,255)), int(random(20,255)), int(random(20,255))));
      numCreatures++;
    }
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < numCreatures; i++) creatures[i].update();
}




function Creature(endSize,x,y,ellipses,hair,strokeW,c){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.ellipses = ellipses;
 this.hair = hair;
 this.numHair = 0;
 this.cStrokeWeight = strokeW;
 this.cColor = c;
 this.cXInc = 0;
 this.cYInc = 0.01;
 this.cSize = 0;
 this.cEndSize = endSize;
 this.easing = 0.05;
 this.angle = 0.0;
 this.matured = false;
 
    if(x >= 500) x -= this.cEndSize;
    else         x += this.cEndSize;
    if(y >= 250) x -= this.cEndSize;
    else         x += this.cEndSize;
    if(hair == 1) this.numHair = 3;//~5, half that, draw through centre, etc.
    if(hair == 2) this.numHair = 6;
    if(hair == 3) this.numHair = 30;//no default value


 this.update = function(){
   if(this.matured) { 
    this.x += (((mouseX - this.x) * this.easing) / 60) + random(-5, 6);
    this.y += (((mouseY - this.y) * this.easing) / 60) + random(-5, 6);
   }else {
    if(this.cSize < this.cEndSize) this.cSize += this.cSizeInc;
    else this.matured = true;
    this.angle += 0.05;
   } 
   this.draw();
 }
 this.draw = function(){
   if(this.matured){
     stroke(this.cColor);
     strokeWeight(this.cStrokeWeight);
     if(this.ellipses == 1){//2 ellipses diagonally
       ellipse(this.x,this.y,this.cSize,this.cSize);
       ellipse(this.x+this.cSize,this.y+this.cSize,this.cSize,this.cSize);
     }
     if(this.ellipses == 2){
       ellipse(this.x,this.y,this.cSize,this.cSize);
       ellipse(this.x,this.y+this.cSize,this.cSize,this.cSize);
       ellipse(this.x+this.cSize,this.y+this.cSize,this.cSize,this.cSize);
     }
     if(this.ellipses == 3){
       ellipse(this.x,this.y,this.cSize,this.cSize);
       ellipse(this.x+this.cSize,this.y,this.cSize,this.cSize);
       ellipse(this.x,this.y+this.cSize,this.cSize,this.cSize);
       ellipse(this.x+this.cSize,this.y+this.cSize,this.cSize,this.cSize);
     }
     var hairAngleInc = TWO_PI/this.numHair;//angle increment for each piece = 360/number of hair lines
     var hairAngle,hairLength,hairCos,hairSin;
     for(var i = 0; i < this.numHair; i++){
       hairAngle = hairAngleInc * i;
       hairCos = cos(hairAngle);
       hairSin = sin(hairAngle);
       hairLength = random(20);
       stroke(this.cColor, random(255));
       line(this.x + (hairCos * -hairLength),this.y + (hairSin * -hairLength), this.x + (hairCos * hairLength),this.y + (hairSin * hairLength)); 
     }
   }else{
     stroke(abs(sin(this.angle) * 255));
     ellipse(this.x,this.y, this.cSize * 5,  this.cSize * 5);
   }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Creatures JS sketch preview]

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `frameRate(fps)`function. What it does is, it specifies the number of frames to be displayed every second. However, If the processor is not fast enough to maintain the specified rate, it will not be achieved. For example, the function call `frameRate(30)` will attempt to refresh 30 times a second. It is recommended to set the frame rate within `setup()`.

Remember, using `draw()` without specifying the frame rate, by default it will run at 60 fps.

Comment: in theory my answer should help, however i just tried to render it myself with the modifications and no much of a difference. Like EboMike said, will advise you to optimize your code following his technique.

Answer (score 7):

Well, there's the good old [random-pause method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266373/one-could-use-a-profiler-but-why-not-just-halt-the-program/317160#317160). It's the "poor man's profiler".

Just snapshot it a few times. That will show you exactly what's taking the most time. Those are the things you should see if you can make faster.
It will show up in increased framerate.