# Using Processing Sketches With Tabs In Processing JS

Tags: processing, processing.js

I've got a Processing sketch that I'd like to display on my site with Processing.js rather than as a Java applet, however I'm not sure it supports tabs - or classes. Does it need to be written as procedural script, or is there an `<include>` I can use - or another option?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered a [Processing related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320162/processing-how-can-i-improve-the-framerate-in-my-program/4330234#4330234) and used classes, but I simply pasted the class after the rest of the program. I don't know if this fully answer your question, but here's [an example](http://hascanvas.com/creatures)

[image: Processing sketch preview]

Comment: Ah yes! That was quite straightforward. Thanks! Also nice processing work. Not sure if you know that Chrome and Firefox have a little console that pops up at the bottom of the viewport when you use println(). So I can see the creatures: 75, or whatever number being printed. Not sure if you want to comment that out of your work. Thanks again.

Comment: @logic-unit I didn't know it was a Chrome/Firefox thing, I thought it was part of the hascanvas site. I left the println() there because it was part of the answer I gave for a question, I didn't write the program (@Miles did),I just refactored it :)  Thanks for the println() tip.

Answer (score 7):

You can also include multiple .pde files in the html canvas tag separated by spaces

`<canvas data-processing-sources="hello-web.pde class.pde"></canvas>`

mentioned near the top of this page: http://processingjs.org/reference/articles/jsQuickStart

Comment: On behalf of [cjlmia](http://stackoverflow.com/users/728077/cjlmia): One caveat: be careful to put the file that contains your setup() and draw() methods as the last item in the list. I have seen inconsistent loading of the sketches when the dependent classes are contained in pde files listed after the pde file that contains your main setup() and draw() methods.