# my code is slow and I have no idea how to fix it?

Tags: processing, draw, slowdown

I'm making a program that you can draw in and when there are more than 38000 _points it starts to lag.

here's the code:

```
public class _point {
  float x = 0;
  float y = 0;

  boolean active = true;

  color c = color(255, 255, 255);

  public void _point() {
  }
  public void change_pos(float x1, float y1, color c1)
  {
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
    c = c1;
  }
  public void u_line(float px, float py)
  {
    if (dist(x, y, px, py) < 15)
    {
      stroke(c);
      strokeWeight(5);
      line(x, y, px, py);
    }
  }
  public void remove_beans()
  {
    if (eraser) {
      if (dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY)<main_tool.radius/2) {
        active = false;
      }
    }
  }
  public void a_line()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < _points.size(); ++i) {
      _point part = _points.get(i);

      if (dist(x, y, part.x, part.y) < 15)
      {
        line(x, y, part.x, part.y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and where its drawn:

```
ArrayList<_point> _points = new ArrayList<_point>();
void draw_beans() {
  for (int i = 0; i < _points.size(); ++i) {
    _point part = _points.get(i);

    if (part.active == false) {
      _points.remove(i);
    }

    if (i != 0 && i != _points.size()-1 && i != _points.size()) {
      OPTIMIZE(_points.get(i+1), part, _points.get(i-1));
    }

    if (i != 0) {
      _point past = _points.get(i-1);

      part.u_line(past.x, past.y);//past.x,past.y
    }
  }
}
```

this is were the points are added to the array:

```
void add_beans() {
  if (!eraser && !IIIINNZ()) {
    _points.add(new _point());
    _point part = _points.get(_points.size()-1);
    part.change_pos(mouseX-transX, mouseY-transY, color(int(color_text0.texts), int(color_text1.texts), int(color_text2.texts)));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < _points.size(); ++i) {
    if (eraser && !IIIINNZ()) {
      _point part = _points.get(i);
      part.remove_beans();
    }
  }
}
```

and an optimization:

```
void OPTIMIZE(_point next, _point thiss, _point prev) {
  if (dist(thiss.x, thiss.y, next.x, next.y)+dist(thiss.x, thiss.y, prev.x, prev.y)<14) {
    thiss.active = false;
  }
}
```

setup:

```
void setup() {
  size(512, 512);
  noCursor();
}
```

draw:

```
void draw() {
  background(#222833);//27,27,33
  textFont(font);

  pushMatrix();
  translate(transX, transY);
  draw_beans();
  popMatrix();

  show_options();

  main_tool.update();

  println(_points.size());
}
```

I have tried to multithread it but the thread doesn't align with the animation thread so there are missing points.

I am using the Processing 3 java library and vscode.

Comment: Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tag the Q with the appropriate language and/or framework.

Comment: This is really incomplete, can you show your definition of `_points`? Giving us your `draw` and `setup` would also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what `OPTIMIZE` and `IIIINNZ` do.

Without being able to run your code and test I can't tell if those function slow it down or is it simply the (re)rendering.

I advise using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to Profile the CPU usage of your sketch(PApplet subclass). The CPU Profiler will list the methods from the slowest:
[image: VisualVM CPU Profiler]

Focus your efforts on the top slowest and try not to sacrifice code readability if possible.

(On code readability I recommend using a [Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) guide overall. It will save time scanning/reading longer and longer programs)

Your question reminds me a little bit of [an older one I answered a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320162/processing-how-can-i-improve-the-framerate-in-my-program/4330234#4330234).

It's similar because of the many lines rendered. In addition yours uses `distance()` (which in turn uses `Math.sqrt()` which can cost the CPU a bit, but as much as rendering. You could use squared distance instead, but that will make the code a bit harder to read and if compared to rendering isn't that slow I'd leave that in).

Essentially there are many point instances that render lines based on threshold distances. Each `stroke()`, `strokeWeight()`, `line()` call will have it's cost.

I've tried to group line rendering into something simpler: a single shape accessing all the point instances:

```
void draw_beans() {
  beginShape(LINES);
  for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
    Point part = points.get(i);
    
    
    if (part.active == false) {
      points.remove(i);
    }

    //if (i != 0 && i != points.size()-1 && i != points.size()) {
    //  OPTIMIZE(points.get(i+1), part, points.get(i-1));
    //}

    if (i != 0) {
      Point past = points.get(i-1);

      //part.u_line(past.x, past.y);//past.x,past.y
      vertex(past.x, past.y);
    }
  }
  endShape();
}
```

This barely made a dent and even if it would've been waaay faster it would've been limiting.

It's worth baring in mind how `line()` is implemented behind the hood for each renderer. Surprisingly, the `FX2D` renderer might work better for your setup (e.g. `size(512, 512, FX2D);`)

Comment: thanks.  i have implemented the FX2D renderer and it helped alot.