# Java - No stack traces available

Tags: java, performance, jvm, stack-trace

my application consumes 100% CPU - out of 200%. When I create a thread dump either by calling `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` or `kill -3`, I see that there are threads that consume a lot of CPU time, but their stack traces unavailable. They are not shown while CPU profiling.

The threads are: `HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread`, `Keep-Alive-Timer` and `process reaper`. Their stack traces however are unavailable.

`Keep-Alive-Timer` and `HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread` should not be native as far as I understand. In addition we don't have special permissions in java.policy or java.security files in jre.

How can I get the stack traces of these threads in order to solve the high CPU consumption?

Comment: You've [tried this, right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266373/one-could-use-a-profiler-but-why-not-just-halt-the-program/317160#317160)

Comment: Ctrl + Break is good for Windows as far as I know, the same option for linux is kill -3, that's what I've tried

Comment: It is very strange that these three consume much CPU. I'd suspected some networking issue, like DDoS of opening/closing SSL connections or something like this.

Comment: We also suspect networking issues, but we can't find the root cause.

Comment: Is this an application server? *Can* you control your security policy to prevent native everything and still see your application function?

Comment: Is it possible to try [jstack?](http://blogs.sun.com/alanb/entry/jstack)

Comment: Going to try it with -m flag for native threads

Answer (score 0):

Use a profiling tool like [visual vm](http://visualvm.java.net/)

It has CPU sampling and profiling support to show where the CPU consumption is.

Comment: Tried. Because there are no stack traces available, profiler does not see these threads