# High CPU with java 1.7 at SocketInputStream.read

Tags: java, sockets, cpu

We have socket based applications running with few clients connecting via sockets.  It has been running without any issues for few years.  We are trying to upgrade to `1.7 JRE` to run the same application.  All the test cases run against that, and at some point the CPU of that server goes 50% or above and stays there.  No issues with memory and the jump in CPU is high.  Thread dumps indicates most of the CPU is at `socketinputstream.read`.  There is not much activity but somehow it shows the issue there.  We are using `1.7.40b43 version of JRE`.

Again when we switch back to 1.6,  everything goes well.  Any ideas where the problem might be?  We did set the flag `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` though it did not seem to be relevant to our issue, but no luck.  We are running our application on VM machines with Windows 2008 (so can not be leap second problem, right?.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the delay between socketinputstream.read is too low?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Profiled app with YourKit, still can't identify the CPU hog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868159/profiled-app-with-yourkit-still-cant-identify-the-cpu-hog)