# find slow-running code

Tags: java, performance, profiling

I've inhereted a multi-threaded Java web app and been tasked with speeding it up. I tried figuring out which parts are responsible for the performance problems by adding logging statements, but this isn't working out.

So, I'm now looking for a tool (a profiler I guess), than can help me to find the code that's responsible for the performance problems. Ideally I'd like to be able to to start the app, execute a few actions, then look a report that shows me where the execution time was spent by class/method.

Due to budgeting constraints, I'm only likely to be able to use free tools, or tools that offer a trial period.

Comment: Sounds like an invitation for a lot of unsubstantiated opinions on which is the best (already seeing that in the answers/comments) :) Anyway, this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler

Comment: *[Simple is best.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/317160/23771)*

Answer (score 6):

For simple evaluations I really like [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) which is shipped with the jdk.

I simply profile the CPU and look at methods, that take the most time.

[image]

Screenshot is from the [jvisualvm page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html).

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans has profile support it's free.

Comment: +1, Netbean's profiler is one of the best around IMO.

Answer (score 0):

jvisualvm will be able to give you an indication where object creation bottlenecks take place - you may be able to do timing profiling with it as well.

it's distributed as part of the modern VM.

Answer (score 0):

VisualVM is free and open source.

http://visualvm.java.net/