# Java profiler to resolve performance issues

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, profiler

Can any one suggest me the Java profiler to identify Threading issues and performance issues in the Java Project. 
Thanks!

Comment: The NetBeans IDE nicely integrates a profiler.

Comment: But I am Using Eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/317160/23771

Answer (score 1):

You can try `jvisualvm` util available in JDK