# Profile instrumentation with relations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling, instrumentation

Visual Studio profiler does not show mesured time affected by method relations. I mean there is method C. It can be called from A or B. I want the profiler to show me that when A calls C there are 10-12 ms spent but when B calls C there are 30-70 ms spent in C. Can you suggest any existing profilers to handle this situation?

Comment: I use [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) of course. If I take 10 stackshots, and C is on 5 of them, that tells me C is responsible for 50% of time. Of those 5, if A is above C on 2 of them, and B is above C on 3 of them, that means 40% of the time used by C comes from being called by A, and 60% from B. All of these numbers are very approximate, but for locating performance problems, approximate is quite good enough.

Comment: So there is nothing. I've started developing such profiler myself cause I need it. The instrumentation part have been already finished.

Comment: I think the ideal profiler would apply artificial intelligence to each stack sample. Failing that, I apply real intelligence to each stack sample. I don't know of any stack-sampler that lets the user actually see the samples (except `rprof`). Of course, I can only do that for a small number of samples, but when I say a small number of samples is more than enough to locate problems, people don't want to hear it. But when they actually try it, they realize it is so. So what people get for all that nice profiler technology is *less speedup !* because they miss opportunities.

Comment: In my case I can't use your solution. My project is multithreaded. Sometimes something goes slow in various places. I just can't catch it. Thanks for rprof but it's not too supported as I see (. But I've already finished my profiler, just need to somehow display collected data.

Comment: My approach to multi-threaded is just treat it as a collection of single threads, [*as in this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/317160/23771). It is more work. You need to look through the threads and figure out which ones are active, and what they're doing. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I made it. I am not sure weather I am going to share it. If you think you that you need it - let me now.
[image: Profiler]