# how to profile a statement used in a method in java

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler

I know how to profile methods in netbeans to see which one is taking the most time, but I wonder if there is a way to find which line of statements in that method is responsible for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: There's a bone-simple way to find that out. [*Look here.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/317160/23771)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best commercial tools you can use (with a 30 days trial) is [Yourkit java profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) which lets you know lots of details about your code , slow methods,dead locks,.... 
There a also some other profilers like [Jprofiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) which I did not use personally
and as free,easy to use you can take a look at java visualvm which comes with JDK 6 and higher.

Comment: Yourkit seems to be very fast, but still it doesn't provide the analysis over statements. I get some stats on methods, but nothing for the statements.

Comment: diff between methods and statements?

Comment: If you mean SQL statement take a look at this http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/cpu_j2ee.jsp