# Enable Debug mode for JVM or get debug build for jdk8?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-8, jdk1.7

I see intermittent pauses in our application where the sync time for a safe point is high.

> 2015-07-27T03:05:18.478-0600: 734.948: Application time: 4.1685198
>   seconds
>            vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
>   733.780: no vm operation                  [     343          0              0    ]      [     0     0  1168     0     0    ]  0    0
>   2015-07-27T03:05:19.647-0600: 734.949: : Total time for which
>   application threads were stopped: 0.0012189 seconds

This leads to a few timeouts as the latency desired is `~100ms`. 
I want to know how do I debug the high sync time. Can I get a debug build for `jdk8` or any other way?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29809469/1362755

Comment: updating the jdk to 1.8.0_45 build helped reduce the high safepoint sync time. Thanks.