# Blocking Locks appearing in code

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling, java-mission-control

I am investigating an ongoing CPU usage issue where it goes high after sometime of usage. I got an alert on one of the nodes that the load was high and I opened Java Mission Control and took a quick Flight Record.

I am attaching the output of what I see. I am not a developer so I need help understanding what I see.

I am looking at the thread locks and see that 3 threads are locked. I opened the stack trace and see a number Request/Response , Socket etc entries.

Any idea what it means ?

[image: Java Mission Control Output]

Comment: If you're not a developer, why are you investigating this issue?

Comment: You should note, that flight recorder only allows you to use it in development unless you have a license for your JVM i.e. it's a commercial feature which you have to pay for.

Comment: @Kayaman I am a Sysadmin. So if the load on the system is high, I am answerable for that. So I am trying to figure out whats happening right now and then get the development team involved on this.

Comment: @JasonStanley This stack trace suggests your program is spending a lot of time logging. I would check the size of the logs.

Answer (score 2):

The image you've shown doesn't show three locked threads, but rather three objects which are the most contended locks. For a general developer-friendly description of what the pieces on the page you're looking at mean, see [the doc on this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr005.html#JSTGD144).

Now, since you've said you're not a developer, let me break things down for you a little:

**What does it mean for an object to be a lock?**

This is a java thing. Java has set up their multithreading locking scheme based around the concept of [monitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)). Basically any object in the language can be used as a lock so that when a thread executes code like:

```
synchronized(myObject){
    //code
}
```

while `//code` is being executed, no other thread can be executing `//other code` in a block like:

```
synchronized(myObject){
    //other code
}
```

(assuming myObject refers to the same actual object each time).

**What does it mean for a lock to be contended?**

Suppose thread A is currently executing `//code` from the example above (assume it takes some non-zero time), and thread B reaches a spot where it wants to try to execute `//other code`. Since the language is set up so that these two portions of code can't be executed at the same time (called [*mutual exclusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), thread b *will have to sit and wait* to execute `//other code` until `//code` is finished. When this happens, we say that the lock for `myObject` is *contended*.

**What are the 3 classes I'm seeing?**

These are the classes of the 3 objects acting as locks which caused the most delay by threads sitting an waiting for them.

**What is the stack trace I'm seeing?**

That is the stack trace to one of the spots where one of the threads spent the most time waiting.

And probably the question you care about most: **Does the information in this profile indicate a performance problem?**

It depends on how long your flight record was taken for, but my opinion (take it with a grain of salt given that I don't know any details of your application) is a rather underwhelming *possibly, but not necessarily*. The total amount of time waiting for the most contended lock was a little over 3 seconds, with an average wait time of a second and a half. This may not sound like a lot (and may not actually be a lot if the waiting happened on a relatively unimportant thread), but for code, 1.5 seconds of waiting can be a lot. Consider this, a guideline for user interface responsiveness is that an operation has to [take less than 0.1 seconds for a user not to notice and less than 1 second for their train of thought to not be interrupted](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/). If your waiting on that lock happened on the thread managing your user interface, the user would have noticed the delay.

My best recommendation to you as a non-developer would be to get the stack trace you receive by looking at the `java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock` object and send it to a developer on your project to examine further.

Also, you mention that a CPU load issue prompted this investigation, so: **Would contended locks cause a high CPU load?**

**No.** When a lock is contended, one or more of the threads is sitting and waiting, which means they won't be using the CPU. As a matter of fact, one of the signs that lock contention could be causing problems is if your CPU load is abnormally low (particualrly on a multi-core machine). Your high CPU usage likely lies elsewhere to be found in your profiling results. To investigate high CPU usage you should try method hotspots or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266373/one-could-use-a-profiler-but-why-not-just-halt-the-program/317160#317160). It will likely be enormously more productive if you have a trained developer looking at it with you.

Comment: Thanks You. this was quite helpful

Comment: @Jason Stanley: See edits- the real meat of the info you want is probably hidden with the `java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock` lock rather than the `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Alternatively it might be with another part of the profiling results (ex: method hotspots) if you really care about the CPU issue (more new edits)

Answer (score 0):

Like many programs, they spend a significant portion of their time logging.  In this case your program is spending a lot of time writing to it's console which I imagine is redirected to a file.  The more you write the longer it takes. esp if you disk subsystem become a bottleneck.  If the logs are going to a screen somewhere, it can slow down depending on what that computer is doing.